# Getting coordinates from json parsing and displaying in mapview?

Tags: android

through jsonparsing i parse all the string values again i need to display the latitude and longitude in the mapview.. where i need to store all the coordinates in a separate array
anyone please help me .. 
 thanks in advance

Comment: where you getting the problem? if you getting the string value then what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how is your func of parseString, I assume that you can get 2 string value of lat and long. The remaining part can be done as followed

```
        String coordinates[] = {"...","..."};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

         p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lon * 1E6));
       //mc is MapView object
        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(15); 

        mapView.invalidate();
```

To display it on the map, you need to create an overlay with a bitmap pinpoint in res/ folder

```
MarkerOverlay mark = new MarkerOverlay();
 listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
         listOfOverlays.add(mark);
        mapView.invalidate();
```

A class of MapOverlay could be defined as such:

```
  class MarkerOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {
      //create a constructor here with p.x and p.y as parameters

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
        boolean shadow, long when) 
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            Point screenPts = new Point();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);  

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                                (int) (p.x * 1E6), 
                                (int) (p.y * 1E6));

                        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, screenPts);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x-16, screenPts.y-32, null); 
                        canvas.drawText(parts[0],screenPts.x-16 , screenPts.y-40, new Paint());
                    }
                }
            }


            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: no need of this **GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (p.x * 1E6),(int) (p.y * 1E6));** you can directly use the p object of GeoPoint in **mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);**